# Restricting the discriminated union type to current property only

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm having a problem achieving proper validation given the types below:

```
type T1 {
  __typename: "T1";
  action: "ACTION_1" | "ACTION_2";
  user: string;
}

type T2 {
  __typename: "T2";
  action: "ACTION_3" | "ACTION_4" | "ACTION_5";
}

type T3 {
  __typename: "T3";
  action: "ACTION_6";
  note: string;
}

type T = T1 | T2 | T3
```

Based on the above, I'm trying to achieve a type that would validate object below:

```
const obj: MappedObj = {
  T1: {
    ACTION_1: "some string",
    ACTION_2: "some string"
  },
  T2: {
    ACTION_3: "some string",
    ACTION_4: "some string",
    ACTION_5: "some string",
  },
  T3: {
    ACTION_6: "some string"
  }
}
```

Basically, I tried to create an indexed type, iterating through `__typename` of `T`, and then in that property to have another iteration of `action`. Ideally, I would like the `action` to be based on the "current" `__typename` but my current solution does not distinguish from different variants of `T` and just requires ALL possible actions to be specified in a object:

```
type MappedObj = { [key in T["__typename"]: { key2 in T["action"]: string } }
```

For each key in `T["typename"]` I get an error in this fashion:

```
Type '{ ACTION_1: string; ACTION_2: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ ACTION_3: string; ACTION_4: string; ACTION_5: string; ACTION_6: string; ts(2739)
```

Is there a way to tie `action` to `__typename` of "current" property?

Comment: Key remapping will make this easy-ish but I’m on mobile now; someone else will probably get here first and I’m envious

Comment: You're looking for [this code](https://tsplay.dev/Wy5knW), I think

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: Okay I’ll write up a proper answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) as introduced in TypeScript 4.1,  you are allowed to iterate over arbitrary union types, not just key-like types, as long as you re-map the members of that union to keys.  That means your `MappedObj` could be defined like this:

```
type MappedObj = {
    [U in T as U["__typename"]]: {
        [P in U["action"]]: string
    }
};
```

We are iterating over the union `T`.  For each member `U` of that union, we make a property whose key is `U["__typename"]` and whose value is the equivalent of `Record<U["action"], string>`.  That produces the type you're looking for:

```
/* type MappedObj = {
    T1: {
        ACTION_1: string;
        ACTION_2: string;
    };
    T2: {
        ACTION_3: string;
        ACTION_4: string;
        ACTION_5: string;
    };
    T3: {
        ACTION_6: string;
    };
} */
```

---

Note that this is also possible without key remapping (and therefore in TypeScript versions earlier than 4.1), but because you're iterating over the union `T["__typename"]`, for each such key `K` you need to extract from `T` the member which is assignable to `{__typename: K}`.  So it could be written like this:

```
type MappedObj = {
    [K in T["__typename"]]: {
        [P in Extract<T, { __typename: K }>["action"]]: string
    }
};
```

using [the `Extract<X, Y>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) which evaluates to the member(s) of the union `X` which are assignable to `Y`.  That's a bit more work than before: remapping can just iterate `U in T`, and without it you have to synthesize `U` from `K in T["__typename"]`.  I usually suggest key remapping nowadays, but it can still be useful to know how to do it a different way.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3gKCpqB9bpIB2AhgLYQBcUARPFQNwZZEDGwAlgPYGVUCCAwjACSAeQBy2OFSgAfagOHjsAJnqNMAVwDOEAE6UtwXWwIBzBgF80afNBjKkqdTjzgIxMj3tqsUFuy4eBVEJAGZpOT5BEOwAFgj5aKUAVjUrGzdYUMd0X1xbDwpqGHCGX39ObkTFCQA2HywCDmAiw2MzS2tbWEd4WVgHORKuzIBZIjBIABMRACMAKxznAG0AVSgTHqItKFXlqny3QqoAXRPKXN8sZYAFDYJd-YquU-OoNpNTZysLBjQAegAVFBuuNJhAZgslr54BdnL5gko4AYjJ8yldMIiJMoUe1zN90Zh7HCMZikmFcWj4VgsXFKR1qWSathkvT8b5fs4SiTSbTamzCVBORYoID-tYMpAoGDpnN5g5kJdMMsANL3WD7Q6EUgQV48jG3dUAUQAHkZ-AAeGAAGlQLgKOsoaosAD4nqxKnr3qizN80JygA)